# Tag icon for actions-on-google vanished?

Tags: support, sponsored-tags

Up until a couple of days ago, there was a Google Assistant logo attached to the [actions-on-google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actions-on-google) tag. It appears to be a sponsored tag (the sponsored links are still on that page, along a large sized Google Assistant logo) and Google still references the tag as the official tag to use for developers to ask questions. Other related tags (such as the google-assistant-sdk) still have their logos.

Did someone at Google forget to pay the bill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good eye! The tag icon disappearing was a result of the configuration date not being updated as we went into a new month. Am sure you'll see it pop up again at some point today as we QA.

Comment: (I use it as a visual cue for what to click on to see more of them, so it caught my eye pretty quickly.)

Looks like it has returned. Thanks!